# maximum size of data sent from a text field in html

Tags: textfield, forms

what is the maximum size of data that can be sent from a text field on clicking the submit button?
I am asking this because the data in my text field comes up to be about 51KB. Will the whole data be sent to the server on clicking the submit button.

Comment: the limitation would probably come from the server, or your browser and OS (~2GB on 32bits systems). Assuming your use the POST Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a limit on the data from a text area , If you want you can restrict the data using max length

Comment: @Query zorro:Are you sure there is no limit?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a guess. I tried with some 6 lac characters event it works but when I paste that huge data in text area browser hanging for a few seconds